# Cascade delete occurring itself in Code-First Entity-Framework(version 5.0)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having following two classes

Class 1:

```
[Table("players")]
public class Player
{
    [Key, Column("id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    <summary>
    /// Video Location w.r.t. Current Screen (Top)
    /// </summary>
    [Column("top")]
    public double Top { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Video Location w.r.t. Current Screen (Width)
    /// </summary>
    [Column("width")]
    public double Width { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Video Location w.r.t. Current Screen (Height)
    /// </summary>
    [Column("height")]
    public double Height { get; set; }




    [Column("group_id")]
    public int group_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("group_id")]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

And my other class is
Class 2:

```
    [Table("groups")]
    public class Group
    {
         [Key, Column("id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
          public int Id { get; set; }

           [Column("guid")]
           public string Guid { get; set; }

           [Column("is_deleted")]
           public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

           [Column("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

   }
```

I am having problem in deleting the group entry from the database.
Whenever i delete any group all the players belonging to the group gets automatically deleted.
I am using   Code-First with Entity-Framework(5.0).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the FKs on your database are set up incorrectly with the relationship going in the wrong direction. IF cascacde delete is set up them you are going to be in trouble if the FK is wrong. If you aren't using FKs then of course you should be.  Hopefully you didn't design your database using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically map that scenario. You could do it like so:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasOptional(x => x.Group).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

This will make the group on a player optional meaning it can exists without a reference to a group and will also instruct your context not to do cascade delete.